# No sound after I install the Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I have installed Ubuntu 9.04 in my laptop, but there is no sound. Can someone give some suggestion about how to fix it? I am a new user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu Wiki "Debugging Sound Problems" page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

In general - first culprit to check is the "Mute" and volume settings.

Other than that, I'd recomment digging the ubuntuforums.org web site, it's a great source for answers about Ubuntu (note I write "Answers" - if you are a novice there are very good chances someone else has already asked and got a useful answer for your problem on that site).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with sudo lshw - this should give you a list of hardware you have installed, and their states- I'd check to make sure the sound card isn't disabled. It might also help to mention your sound card in the question, since some sound cards can be problamatic, and this might narrow down the possible fixes somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 9.04 had many growing problems with Sound because of the change in default sound subsystems. Try installing Ubuntu 9.10 instead if you can and see if that fixes your problems.